# How to Detect an Empty Value

Tags: python, input, null

I'm currently making a Python script for account creation. My script is as follows:

```
import csv
nms = []
with open('nms.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        nms.append(row)
counter = 0        
## End of tings
while True:        
    print ("Please enter your user name. This must be unique.")
    usernm = input ("")
    while True:
        if nms[1][counter] != (""):
            print (".")
        else:
            break
        if usernm == nms[1][counter]:
            print ("Unfortunately this user name is in use. Please try a different user name.")


        counter = counter + 1

print ("end")
```

The issue is that with the way I've made my script, where I've tried to stop the program checking if the username is equal to a blank value, it of course errors, is there a better method of detecting a null value? So that when it actually see's one, it will break out of the while loop? The rest of my program thus far seems to work fine.

Comment: Python has `None`, not null. Empty strings are not `None`, though. What is the error message that you get?

Comment: If the usernames are unique, why not a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the need for the counter variable, but you can check if an item exists in an iterable object with `in`

```
if usernm in nms:
    # user already exists
```

> I've tried to stop the program checking if the username is equal to a blank value

It looks like you checked if the second value of `nms` at the character of the index `counter` is an empty string. You didn't check the username that was input at all.

```
if usernm.trim() == "":
    # username is blank
```

Comment: So I could write if usernm in nms[1] and that would check if that username was in any of the names on that line? (txt file looks like this: with 'usr' above it)
geoff,tim,regan,orange

Comment: `nms` is a list of elements. `nms[1]` is only the second element in that list

Comment: Nono, there is more to the TXT file, the [1] is the second line, where all the usernames are, the [i] was running through every user name.

Comment: You may want split the CSV row on commas so that you get usernames, not a string of comma separated names

Comment: If you print the value of `nms[1][counter]`, it will be one character unless you split `nms[1]` on commas

Comment: Yes, I understand, thank you. I believe I just made this a whole lot harder on myself by forgetting about the 'in' command! The program works flawlessly now, thank you very much.